# How do i remove this bulb from my bathroom fixture?

Tags: lighting, bathroom

My bathroom fixture has one of these and I can seem to remove it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a glove (in case the bulb shatters), push it sideways (assuming it's horizontal) and then pull forward.

When replacing, do not get skin oils on the new bulb... it is highly likely to break. You can use a paper towel or something similar.

Comment: I tried pushing it sideways then pulling forward and that thing is tough!  I wonder if its seized in my socket.